# Use regex (javascript) to check if all letters in a string are consonants

Tags: javascript, regex, algorithm

The title is pretty self-explanatory; I want to develop an algorithm using regex that tests if a string contains ONLY consonants (in any order).

For example, if I had three strings to test:

```
1. ('happy')
2. ('apples')
3. ('sdfghjkl')
```

I would want the code to only return true for string number 3.

I think it should be something like:

```
if ((/[^aeiou]+/i . . .)) {
 // not relevant
}
```

I get stuck on what to add to the condition to make the code work

I am thankful for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex:

```regex
^[^aeiou]+$
```

You need to add `^` and `$` to the ends of the regex so that you can confirm that the matched characters (consonants) span the whole range of the string.

You can match a string against this regex using the [`test` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) on the regex:

```js
var testStrings = ['happy', 'apples', 'sdfghjkl'];
var allConsonantsRegex = /^[^aeiou]+$/i;

testStrings.forEach(string => {
  if (allConsonantsRegex.test(string)) {
    console.log(string, 'is all consonants');
  } else {
    console.log(string, 'is has some vowels');
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that this will also accept special characters and accented vowels as “all consonants”.

Comment: @DidierL Yes; one may want to change `[^aeiou]` to `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]`, or combine positive and negative checks using [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like `((?![aeiou])\w)+`.